# Launch Fancybox iframe on Page Load

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, fancybox

I have a page that uses fancybox to open a gallery and iframes for forms.  I am wondering if I can have a hidden iframe link launch on page load while the others only open when user click on them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use hidden *iframes*, I think is a bad idea (even visible *iframes* are a bad idea too ;)

Try this instead

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $.fancybox({
        href: "http://jsfiddle.net", 
        type: "iframe"
    });
}); // ready
```

**Notice** that the URL in the `href` option corresponds to what you would set in the `src` attribute of your *iframe*

**<kbd>[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rJqq6/1/)</kbd>**